# "Шафа на одежу" чи "шафа для одежі"

Tags: прийменники

[Тут](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/pryjmennyky) викопав, що треба казати "шафа **на** одежу" замість "шафа **для** одежі" і "кошик **на** старі папери" замість "кошик **для** старих паперів", але я ніколи в житті і близько не чув таких висловів.

Який з варіантів правильний, чи можна казати і так, і так?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Із поданої сторінки:

> прийменник *для* буде слушний там, де говориться, що певну річ призначено для людини, тварини або для якоїсь *ширшої потреби* <...> Зате, коли мовиться, що якийсь предмет призначено на певні конкретні речі, тоді треба шукати інших прийменників

- "Шафа на одяг" - шафа, в яку покладуть конкретний одяг і більше нічого.
- "Шафа для одягу" - шафа, призначена для одягу в принципі.

Я це так розумію, мабуть тому що у моєму регіоні словосполучення накшталт "мішок на цукор" і "мішок для цукру" мають дещо відмінні значення, так само, як, наприклад, "чашка на чай" і "чашка для чаю":

- чашка на чай - чашка, у яку буде наливатися конкретний чай (який щойно заварили)
- чашка для чаю - чашка, яка призначена для чаю (а не для кави).
- мішок на цукор - мішок, у який скоро засипеться конкретний цукор (який привезуть)
- мішок для цукру - мішок, призначений для цукру (а не для борошна).

У англійській у даних випадках після "на" стояв би означений артикль.

У цьому контексті твердження автора для мене виглядає трохи дивно, бо він сам пише про *конкретні речі*, але "листи і газети" та "старі папери" - це не конкретні речі, це неозначена множина речей.

Проте це моє суб'єктивне бачення.

Крім того:

> Так само **треба казати**: «поштова скринька на листи й
>   газети», «кошик на старі папери», «миска на борщ». **Кажуть у народі ще**:
>   «мішок під жито», «одежа про свято й про будень», «книжка до читання».

Тобто, автор практично ставить знак рівності між "*треба казати*" і "*у народі кажуть*".
Оскільки зараз у народі кажуть "*для* одежі" і "*для* паперів", то даний варіант мав би бути прийнятним навіть на думку Антоненка-Давидовича.

Варто також звернути увагу на те, що з часу написання тієї книги пройшло майже 50 років і цілком можливо, що тоді прийменник "на" мав більше поширення. Проте сучасна українська мова явно схиляється до "шафи для одягу".

Тому можна вважати, що обидва варіанти можуть вживатися і жоден з них не є "неправильним".